# Unable to extract duration info using ffprobe, commas in filenames are messing up my for loop

Tags: batch, ffprobe

This here batch script creates a list of files from `%folder%` using `%wildcards%`, then creates a mirrored directory on drive `c:` containing a txt version of each file like `every file.mkv.txt`, which contain data of the original files like `path-to-file/duration/size`.

```
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
:: adder fails with filenames with ampersand "&". investigate
for /f "delims=" %%v in ('dir "%folder%\%wildcards%" /b /s /a-d 2^>nul') do (
    if not exist "c:%%~pv" mkdir "c:%%~pv"
    if not exist "c:%%~pnxv.txt" for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=," %%i in ('"%ffprobe%" -v quiet -show_entries "format=duration" -of csv "%%v"') do (
        rem record path-to-file/duration/size into mirror files
        echo %%v/%%i/%%~zv>"c:%%~pnxv.txt"
    )
)
```

Is succeeds on some files and fails with others, I think it has something to do with commas `,` within the part where `ffprobe` is executed to the file `%%v`. It looks like I need to use comma as a delimiter since the duration is in formatted like `format,94.436000`. This stopped working ever since I started needing quotes for the `%ffprobe%` variable (where path to ffprobe.exe is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has something to do with commas (`,`) within the part where ffprobe is executed to the file %%v.:

```bath
:: adder fails with filenames with ampersand "&". investigate`
```

Just try add `2>&1` in `ffprob` command.
Also replace `echo string,with &, and commas` to:
`echo+ & <nul set /p .="Str,ing,s with & and com,mas" >>file`

```bath
for /f tokens^=* %%v in ('dir "%folder%\%wildcards%" /b /s /a-d 2^>nul')do 2>nul mkdir "c:%%~pv" & if not exist "c:%%~pnxv.txt" (
    for /f usebackq^tokens^=1*delims^=^, %%i in (`2^>^&1 "%ffprobe%" -v quiet -show_entries "format=duration" -of csv "%%v"`)do (
        echo+ & <nul set /p .="%%v/%%j/%%~zv">>"c:%%~pnxv.txt"))
```

---

**Obs.:** About the same thing: `2>nul mkdir folder` vs `if not exist folder (create)do not do(ignore)`...

By using `mkdir folder`, you can create folder if it does not exist in one action, in an already existing/does not create one, it just returns a warning/message informing the existence, it is not a collapse/disaster.

It is an action with no effective impact for the loop/bat running, requiring only a command with due predictive treatment of possible non-execution where it is not necessary `[ run (if folder exists warning) omit ] and continue`..., which is perfectly fine resulting from omitting error/warning with `2>nul mkdir Folder_If_Or_Not_Exist & continue`